# How can I run a command when a certain message is dumped to /var/log/messages?

Tags: syslogd

I'm suffering under some bug that makes pulseaudio dump millions of messages in my syslog:

```
Oct 17 15:58:38 host pulseaudio[3757]: alsa-sink.c: Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings. (Old: 352768/176384, New 65536/32768)
```

That amounts to 3GB of wasted disk space every day. The solution is to run this command:

```
/etc/init.d/alsasound restart
```

That fixes the issue. Unfortunately, it takes some time to notice that the bug is happening. So my question: Is there a program which can check for `pulseaudio` and `Resume failed, couldn't restore original fragment settings` and run the above command *once* (even though the message will appear at least a dozen times)?